# Database table with two possible unique keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, primary-key

I have a table where I'm struggling to figure out how to best structure it. It is supposed to house the metadata for a bunch of files, and for each file we have the following information:

- filename
- filesize
- lastmodified
- md5 (sometimes)

I want the unique key to be on `md5`, but in the case that the md5 is `NULL` I want it to fall back on `filename+filesize`. Yes, the filename+filesize isn't a perfect match, but it is about 99.9% accurate from an analysis I've done, and almost 100% accurate on our filenames over 24 chars.

What would be the best way to store this key? Should I add an app-generated column (or trigger?) something like:

```
COALESCE(md5, CONCAT(filename, filesize))
```

Or how is this 'multi-key' thing usually done in practice?

Comment: Where does the md5 come from, could you manually create the missing values and add on insert if missing?

Comment: @Stu no it's the asset's md5 -- often I don't have access to the file, and sometimes I do but the files are quite big and would take a long time to generate (~100GB video).

Comment: for performance reason i would stick to one primary key. i've had issues with composite keys including null values.

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO how would you suggest doing that? a trigger? in he application before the insert? etc.

Comment: I think that to give a useful answer you should specify something more about your application. What happen when you try to insert a new record with a md5 already existing? This cannot happen; or you replace the record if filename and size is different? You give an error? Ignore the operation? Similarly for insertion of records with md5 null.

Answer (score 1):

```
filesize BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
md5 BINARY(16) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id?)  -- UNIQUE
INDEX(filename, filesize),  -- or UNIQUE?
UNIQUE(md5)    -- ok to have multiple NULLs
```

And

```
( SELECT ...
    WHERE md5 = UNHEX(?) )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ...
    WHERE filename = ?
      AND filesize = ? )
ORDER BY md5 DESC      -- give preference to non-NULL
LIMIT 1                -- Either the md5 one or some one with the desired size
```

Yes, a table can have multiple UNIQUE keys, but it is rather rare.  And it is often a sign of poor schema design.

I avoided `COALESCE()` because it is not sargeable, hence slow.  The code above will be two quick index lookups, plus a trivial sort afterwards.

Comment: thanks. Out of curiosity, why do you store `md5` as BINARY(16) instead of CHAR(32) ?

Comment: @David542 - takes half the space.  It does, however, require app code to do the `UNHEX()` and `HEX()`.  For grins, I once used Base64 and `CHAR(22) COLLATE ascii_bin`.  That was a compromise between the readability of `SELECT *` and saving some space.

Answer (score 0):

i would go for 2 keys (both non unique) :

- a key on your md5 column
- and a key on your filename + filesize

plus a normal auto increment primary key

when you do a sql query mysql will decide which index to use automatically.

all thos 3 requests shoudl work. you can also add the explain keyword in front of the select query to check index use and bottlenecks.

```
explain select * from files where md5 = 'xxx';
explain select * from files where filename = 'xxx' and size = 'xxx'
explain select * from files where md5 = 'xxx' or (filename = 'xxx' and size = 'xxx')
```

Comment: that defeats the whole purpose...both keys need to be unique (unless they're null)

Comment: theorically, 2 files can have same content, then same md5 right ? unique constraint would prevent that. you can do a unique constraint if you want

Comment: I think you're suggesting what to do for query performance (thus the explains), I don't care about queries, I just care about integrity and schema at this point.

Comment: you should not use null values in the md5 column if you want it to work. then you have a unique key of 3 columns. here is an explianation for the null values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086382/mysql-compound-keys-and-null-values

Comment: The one with the `OR` will do a full table scan.

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO - that is one chance in 9 trillion that a data set of 9 trillion different files will include a pair with the same md5.  (That comes from the approximation of (2*2^128)^(1/3).)

Answer (score -1):

Your logic seams fine,
I would just make simple adjustment to have ID column that is autoincrement and not null for every row and if possible to be primary and do the unique key based on that

Suggestion -> concat(ID,"*",md5,"*",concat(filename, filesize))

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQLsl.png)

that way you ensure that you will have always unique key for every row,

having almost unique will not help in data modeling, you stated that you have 99.9% accurate that will mean that there are multiple unique keys, which is not good for ER model, and when joining tables by that key it can make many-many joins and duplicate the data.

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but putting the `ID` a the start of the coalesce would automatically make that the value for every row. Do you mean to put it at the end?

Comment: Also, when/where would you populate that constructed key? In a trigger? In the application before inserting? Or where?

Comment: @finally -- why the extra `" "` in the coalesces? Isn't the point of a coalesce to get the first non-null value?

Comment: hey, it can be in a trigger, usually I do it with ETL, but you can add new column when you have all the data with the specific criteria, form the table first, then add new column that will make the key based on whatever you decide :)

Comment: See the update with picture, how I thought it should go, in this view it doesn't show good format

Comment: i may be wrong but coalesce here makes no sens, because id is always defined, and string are always defined. did you mean concat instead ?

Comment: you are right! thanks for spotting this, was typing fast :)

Comment: Leave out `ID`!!

Comment: Don't need a trigger if you use a "generated" column.